# Regex to add new line before CSS media query with sed, keeping CSS media query indentation

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm trying to create a sed expression to add a new line before a media query, but if run the expression again then it should not add the new line twice.

Currently I can add a new line after a semicolon or after an opening bracket, but when I try to check that "@media" has to be after in order to add the new line then the expression do not work.

```
sed -e 's/\([;{]\)\(\|\)/\1\n\2/' styles.less
```

Also I can add a line before media query, preserve its indentation, but not able to detect if it is preceded by ";" or "{". I don't want duplicate new lines if the command is run twice.

```
sed -ie 's/\(\s*\)@media/\n\1@media/' estilos.less
```

Just in case, I'm using CSS comb (with ATOM), which does a lot of things for my LESS or SASS files, but does not create this newline before the media queries.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add examples of input and expected output?

Comment: sed is for doing `s/old/new/`, that is all. It's not the right tool for inserting lines before or after other lines and it's certainly not for anything more complicated like checking if a line already exists before inserting it before some regexp or string match. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and you'll get a clear, simple awk answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but it sounds like what you're looking for is:

```
awk '/@media/ && (p!=""){print ""} {p=$0} 1' file
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
here are 3
        first:
        @media
            second:
            @media
    third (blank line already present):

    @media
occurences

$ awk '/@media/ && (p!=""){print ""} {p=$0} 1' file
here are 3
        first:

        @media
            second:

            @media
    third (blank line already present):

    @media
occurences
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` POSIX BRE doesn't support `\s` shorthand. You have to use corresponding character class `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` (without `\n`). If you are in need of a newline character before media queries (`@media`) that doesn't follow a linebreak (`^[\r\t\f\v ]*$`) you could do this:

```
sed -i '/^[\r\t\f\v ]*$/{N;/@media/!{P;D;};b;};/@media/i\

' file
```

Address matches blank lines then it reads next line to pattern space. If it doesn't match a `@media` it prints every thing up to first newline character from pattern space (`P`), deletes it (`D`) and passes control back to process remaining line in PS (restarts cycle). If it matches `@media` it jumps over all commands and prints whole pattern space.

If all above conditions weren't matched, on matching a `@media` a linebreak will be inserted before current line using `i` command.